FFT for the Estimation of Power Spectra (Welch's Method) - DFT Definition
I was reading Peter Welch's famous paper "The Use of Fast Fourier Transform for the Estimation of Power Spectra: A Method Based on Time Aver. aging Over Short, Modified Periodograms" the other day and stumbled upon a weird definition of the DFT.
He begins by letting

$X(j), j=0,...,N-1$ be a sample from a stationary, second-order stochastic sequence. Assume for simplicity that $E(X)=0. Let X(j)$ have spectral density $P(f), |f| ≤ 1/2$. We take segments, possibly overlapping, of length $L$ with the starting points of these segments $D$ units apart. Let $X1(j),j=0,...,L-1$ be the first such segment. Then
$X_1 = X(j), j=0,...,L-1$
$X_2 = X(j+D), j=0,...,L-1$
...
$X_k = X(j+(K-1)D), j=0,...,L-1$

He then takes a window function $W(j), j=0,...,L-1$ and forms the sequences $X_1(j)W(j),...,X_k(j)W(j)$ for which he takes the finite Fourier transforms $A_k(j)$.
These $A_k$ are defined by him as:

$A_k(n) = \frac{1}{L} \sum_{j=0}^{L-1} X_k(j)W(j)e^{-2kijn/L}$

The part I don't understand is the $e^{-2kijn/L}$, specifically why he's using the index $k$ there instead of $\pi$. In general, I'm missing the $\pi$ in this expression.
This source (https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Welch_s_Method.html) states the argument with a $\pi$ instead of a $k$. Further down in his paper, Welch also adds zero-padding to the $X_k$ with $L'$ zeros giving $M=L+L'$ and defines $A_k(n)'$ as:

$A_k'(n) = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{j=0}^{L-1}X_k(j)W(j)e^{-2\pi ijn/L}$

Here, he also lists $\pi$ instead of $k$.
Welch's paper can be found here and is open access:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1161901?casa_token=1rXSvY4zJagAAAAA:86PsZ4-nNeoBjnm_1fxJhuZATp9gTJWrqF7__t2rkzCt1xAfSbkoH8U-hojmfduG57N-_EIb
Is this a mistake, maybe even a scanning mistake (Xerox Bug)? Or am I missing something?
